# changing links in html to be ready for wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

So basically, I want to put my html website on wordpress, I found a way to do it without changing my html too much, however, my only issue now, is because the js and image file now have to stored in different folders, I am trying to figure out a way to automatically update the links (hrefs) in the html files with the url address of files, so when the page loads it detects the images and works properly with the scripts

Comment: can you share your code where the problem is? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what file structure are they at the moment? what will they be once wordpress is set up? relative links might be useful...

Comment: Are you seeking the code??? Something like <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png'; ?>

Comment: when i made the website all my images were in a folder called images and my js in a folder called js, but now all my images are in the file path mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/customtheme/images, and my scripts are in mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/customtheme/js
im wondering if there is a faster/automatic way to update all the links that to go through even page and manually change the file path

Comment: Then use this to display images: <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png'; ?> and use this for the js files: <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/file.js'; ?>

Comment: I dont see how that will automatically update all the links in the html text so that they will file the images and js correctly. I feel like it might require a scripy to add wp-content/themes/customtheme/ infront of the file path, and I also need it to remove .html from all the internal links to pages

Comment: is there a way to automatically apply get_template_directory_uri() to all the links when the page loads